# Renaming photos to ph01, ph02 .. ph99 in java

Tags: java, format, formatter

I need to rename photos to format photo01, photo02, photo03 ... photo 99
I'm using String.Format

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {


        Log.d("format", String.format("photo%02d", i++));
    }
```

But i have only even nubmers:
photo02
photo04
..photo18
Why? And how i can get photo01, photo99 result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` twice: once in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
```

and once inside the loop:

```
Log.d("format", String.format("photo%02d", i++));
```

It should be

```
Log.d("format", String.format("photo%02d", i + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `i++` in the `String.format` and start the loop with `1` instead of `0`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    Log.d("format", String.format("photo%02d", i));
}
```